# Can IL disassembler can show the data inside Embedded resources

Tags: c#, embedded-resource, il

I was working on some encryption in C#. I wanted to hide my key and thought of Embedded resources. I am not sure whether a hacker can get it using IL disassembler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they most certainly can. And this is not specific to .Net resources, the same applies to resources in unmanaged applications. Resources are meant for convenient storage, not for security.

And if you don't understand such basic concepts yet, I think you shouldn't be implementing seriously meant encryption. Doing encryption correctly is **hard**.

In general, if your program can access some data (e.g. the key) and the program can run on attacker's machine, you should expect that the attacker will have access to it too.

Comment: Not inside something which will be available to the attacker, no. Pretty much the only safe place is on your server, assuming you don't let the user access it directly.

Answer (score 1):

A hacker will also retrieve resources. The best bet you can do is using an obfuscator like Dotfuscator Community Edition. It is only available in VS Professional tho.

[image: ILSpy]

Comment: What exactly will an obfuscator do to resources?

Comment: Some obfuscators will also 'scramble' resources. But those are pretty expensive. Nevertheless, you can always get the resources somehow, because at some point they will be stored in memory. Using a debugger is a good start. But with a good obfuscator you can be sure that you sorted out most 'hackers'...